# Beautifulsoup Strainer to strain items from a specific container only

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Is it possible to make a Beautifulsoup Strainer that strains all 'order-cards' from 'container-01' only (without 'order-cards' from other containers)?
Below the sample HTML

```
<div class="items-container" container-id="container-01">
    <div class="order-card">order_01
        <div class="item-card">item1</div>
        <div class="item-card">item2</div>
        <div class="item-card">item3</div>
        <div class="item-card">item4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="order-card">order_02
        <div class="item-card">itemA</div>
        <div class="item-card">itemB</div>
        <div class="item-card">itemC</div>
        <div class="item-card">itemD</div>
    </div>
    <div class="order-card">order_03
        <div class="item-card">itemW</div>
        <div class="item-card">itemX</div>
        <div class="item-card">itemY</div>
        <div class="item-card">itemZ</div>
        <div class="item-card">item</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="items-container" container-id="container-02">
    <div class="order-card">order_53
        <div class="item-card">item_7</div>
        <div class="item-card">item_8</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="items-container" container-id="container-03">
    <div class="order-card">order_13
        <div class="item-card">item_16</div>
        <div class="item-card">item_17</div>
        <div class="item-card">item_18</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What I have so far is the code below which strains ALL 'order-cards' from ALL containers.

**The goal is** that 'page_soup' contains ALL 'order-card' items that are in 'container-01' only.

The following loop then uses that 'page_soup' to iterate through each item in 'order-card' to get the details from each 'item-card'.

**rephrased above!**
*The goal is* to get the details from each 'item-card' that are in 'container-01' only.

There is no need for parsing any other containers than 'container-01'.

```
only_item_cells = SoupStrainer('div', attrs={"class":"order-card"})
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page_html, 'html.parser', parse_only=only_item_cells)
```

Following that is a loop that gets the details from ALL the 'item-cards' in ALL containers. In fact, that is NOT wanted, as the output includes items from containers other than 'container-01' only.

Running Python 3.8.8, on Anaconda, Win64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the appropriate attribute as you have indicated:

`only_item_cells = SoupStrainer('div', attrs= {"container-id": "container-01"})`

Comment: Your answer of course is correct. I had to rephrase the goal as I have not defined the goal with enough clarity. Essentially 'page_soup' should contain only 'order-cards' from 'container-01'.